# Eclipse RCP visible command depending on active view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I need to show/hide a command in toolbar depending on active view. how can i do that. any help will be appreciated.

i am trying using the visiblewhen  but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code adds the action to the toolbar when the view is on focus.

```
 <visibleWhen
        checkEnabled="false">
     <with
           variable="activePartId">
        <equals
              value="com.example.activeViewID">
        </equals>
     </with>
  </visibleWhen>
```

Comment: The following code also workds    `<visibleWhen     checkEnabled="false">  
    <with  
    variable="activePart">  
    <instanceof  
                                     value="dk.bording.viking.rcp.ui.views.VikingMainView">  
    </instanceof>  
    </with>  
    </visibleWhen>`

Comment: it workes for me like a charm :) i am using 3.8 which version you are using 4.2?